# Can i move file for two folders? Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone

My dropzone form

```
<div align="center">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="add" onclick='add_img()'>Adicionar imagens <i class="lni-check-mark-circle"></i></button>
</div>
<span  id="menos_img"></span>
<span style="display: none;" id="mais_img">
    <div class="m-auto">
        <form action="clients_images_update.php" style="min-height: 0px;" method="POST" class="dropzone">
            <input type="hidden" name="clients_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="users_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]["id"]; ?>" />
        </form>
        <div align="center">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="window.location.reload();">Atualizar <i class="lni-check-mark-circle"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="cancela();">Cancelar <i class='lni-cross-circle'></i></i></button>
        </div>          
    </div>
</span>
```

My upload file:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $source_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $id."_".$fileName;
    //$targetFile   = $id."_".strtotime("now").$fileName;
    $target_path = "img/clients/".$targetFile;

    $array["filename"] = $targetFile;
    $array["main"] = (int)($db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE clients_id = :clients_id;", array("clients_id" => $id), false) == 0);
    $array["clients_id"] = $id;


    if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path)) {
        $db->insert("images", $array);
    }
    $db->insert("log", array("action" => "image", "inserted_on" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), "users_id" => $_POST["users_id"], "clients_id" => $id));
}
```

I want to upload the files to 2 folders. I've tried to do the same process, but to store in the 2 folder but the upload is not done. I tried, added this code excerpt with the code made above but it doesn't upload

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $source_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $id."_".$fileName;
    //$targetFile   = $id."_".strtotime("now").$fileName;
    $target_path = "img/clients/thumbs/".$targetFile;
    if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path)) {
    }
}
```

The complete code I tried (relative to the upload of the images) is this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $source_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $id."_".$fileName;
    //$targetFile   = $id."_".strtotime("now").$fileName;
    $target_path = "img/clients/".$targetFile;
    $target_path2 = "img/clients/thumbs/".$targetFile;
    $array["filename"] = $targetFile;
    $array["main"] = (int)($db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE clients_id = :clients_id;", array("clients_id" => $id), false) == 0);;
    $array["clients_id"] = $id;


    if (move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path)) {
        $db->insert("images", $array);
    }
    image::resize($source_path, "img/clients/thumbs/".$targetFile, 100, 100);
    $db->insert("log", array("action" => "image", "inserted_on" => date("Y-m-d 
H:i:s"), "users_id" => $_POST["users_id"], "clients_id" => $id));    
    if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path1)) {
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` **moves** the file from temp folder to destination folder, so you need to copy it from first to second folder.

Comment: @Triby Hello! I've tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: please edit your question and add the code you've tried, so we can see what's wrong with that and help you to solve it.

Comment: @Triby i already edited the question with the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's see what you're doing wrong:

```
// You're moving the original file right here, this is fine
if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path)) {
    $db->insert("images", $array);
}

// This won't work, because you're trying to access orginal file (moved already)
image::resize($source_path, "img/clients/thumbs/".$targetFile, 100, 100);
$db->insert("log", array("action" => "image", "inserted_on" => date("Y-m-d 
    H:i:s"), "users_id" => $_POST["users_id"], "clients_id" => $id));    

// Now you're trying to move again the original file
if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path1)) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Then, the logic is simplier:

First: If there is a file, move it to it's destination and keep it without modifications

Second: Create the thumb and save it in its corresponding folder, you don't need to copy, because the file is already there

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $source_path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFile = $id."_".$fileName;
    $target_path = "img/clients/".$targetFile;
    $array["filename"] = $targetFile;
    $array["main"] = (int)($db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE clients_id = :clients_id;", array("clients_id" => $id), false) == 0);;
    $array["clients_id"] = $id;

    // Move original file
    if(move_uploaded_file($source_path, $target_path)) {
        $db->insert("images", $array);

        // Create thumb only if the file was moved, otherwhise you'll get errors
        // Your source is the file moved, not the one on temp folder
        image::resize($target_path, "img/clients/thumbs/".$targetFile, 100, 100);

        $db->insert("log", array("action" => "image", "inserted_on" => date("Y-m-d 
            H:i:s"), "users_id" => $_POST["users_id"], "clients_id" => $id));    
    }
}
```